# NodeJS: promise worked insead of async/await

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have seed file

```
require('dotenv').config()

const db = require('./db');
const logger = require('./logger.js')
require('../models/adminModel')
var Admin = require('mongoose').model('Admins');

const seedAdmin = async () => {
  const new_admin = new Admin({email: "xyx@xyz.com", password: "admin@123"});
  await new_admin.save(function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      logger.error(`ERROR: ${err}`)
    logger.success(`Admin user created sucessfully with email: ${new_admin.email}`)
  });

  return 'resolved'
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  var result = await seedAdmin();
  console.log(result);
  process.exit();
}

asyncCall();
```

output of this code is

```
calling
resolved
```

I have written this code after researching

```
require('dotenv').config()

const db = require('./db');
const logger = require('./logger.js')
require('../models/adminModel')
var Admin = require('mongoose').model('Admins');


function seedAdmin() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const new_admin = new Admin({email: "xyx@xyz.com", password: "admin@123"});
    new_admin.save(function(err, result) {
      if (err)
        logger.error(`ERROR: ${err}`)
        resolve('resolved');
      logger.success(`Admin user created sucessfully with email: ${new_admin.email}`)
      resolve('resolved');
    });
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  var result = await seedAdmin();
  console.log(result);
  process.exit();
}

asyncCall();
```

outpute is correct

```
calling
✔  success   Admin user created sucessfully with email: xyx@xyz.com
resolved
```

According to this statment first code should work
Async function returns a promise. The converse is also true. Every function that returns a promise can be considered as async function

I am not able to understand what is missing it it, I am new to Nodejs Help will be appreciated

Comment: You are right about async functions returning a promise, but the reason the second block works and the first one doesn’t is because of the admin.save method having a callback function. In the second block, the promise is structured to only resolve the promise when the callback is executed. The first block will resolve right away, as the callback will not be awaited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't provide the doc for the `new_admin.save()` interface, but in 99% of the cases when an interface supports both promises and the older callback style, if you pass a callback, then it will NOT return a promise.

So, when you do this:

```
  await new_admin.save(function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      logger.error(`ERROR: ${err}`)
    logger.success(`Admin user created sucessfully with email: ${new_admin.email}`)
  });
```

You're passing a callback to `admin.save()` and thus it does NOT return a promise.  So, the `await` does nothing useful. It doesn't wait for that async operation to be done.  `await` only does something useful if the value it is awaiting is a promise.

Instead, don't mix plain callbacks and promises.  Use the promise entirely.

```
const seedAdmin = async () => {
  const new_admin = new Admin({email: "xyx@xyz.com", password: "admin@123"});
  try {
      let result = await new_admin.save();
      logger.success(`Admin user created sucessfully with email: ${new_admin.email}`)
      return 'resolved';
  } catch(err) {
      // log and rethrow so caller still sees error
      logger.error(`ERROR: ${err}`)
      throw err;
  }
}
```

Or, without using `await', you can just do this:

```
const seedAdmin = () => {
    const new_admin = new Admin({email: "xyx@xyz.com", password: "admin@123"});
    return new_admin.save().then(result => {
      logger.success(`Admin user created sucessfully with email: ${new_admin.email}`)
      return 'resolved';
    }).catch(err => {
       // log and rethrow so caller still sees error
       logger.error(`ERROR: ${err}`)
       throw err;        
    });
};
```

Comment: `Admin` appears to be a mongoose model, so yes the behaviour you described does apply to it.

Comment: Thanks for giving understanding , I understand concept now.